# What is the best approach to build a script with 10 users, each performing a different flow within a web app?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to write a script in which 10 virtual users apply load on a web app by each performing a slightly different flow, concurrently, within the same application after they log in.

I know that I can just place 10 thread groups each with 1 user and define a different flow under each thread group but then when I want to modify the number of users per any given flow, I will have to perform changes in all of the thread groups.

Is that the best approach at my disposal or is there another smarter (more easily maintainable) approach I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach with 10 thread groups should be ok, you don't have to hard-code the number of users as `1` or whatever, you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the Thread Group like:

[image]

If you don't provide any value it will default to `1` and in case you need to increase the number of users you will be able to put the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
users=100
```

and next time you run your test each Thread Group will kick off 100 virtual users resulting in 1000 total users.

It is also possible to pass the value via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jusers=100 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

whatever you pass via `-J` command-line argument will override anything in *user.properties* file.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

It is also possible to configure JMeter's virtual users to execute different Samplers or flows within the bounds of the same Thread Group by using:

- [Throughput Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
- [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
- [Weighted Switch Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/wsc/WeightedSwitchController.md)
- [If Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)